# I'm trying to find the "math" way to calculate the number of elements in X amount of packs, those packs made out of 5 "kinds"

Tags: combinatorics

The thing is the following, i have 5 colours with same or different amount of elements per colour.
For example, let's say i have pink, peach, purple, mint, and green. And I have varing amounts per colour... so:

| Colour | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Pink | 242 |
| Peach | 250 |
| Purple | 240 |
| Mint | 240 |
| Green | 252 |

I would like to be able (if possible) to calculate how many packs of 3 colours (same amount per colour in a pack) i could make (and the amount per colour in that pack), i realize there's a lot of combinations available, but if i could restrict the amount of packages i can make (let's say not more than 10 packs) that would be helpful, i'm not sure how to do the math on it, after i have the math i'll translate it into code.

Example of end product after applying the "formula" if possible, once or many times until no units are left, or the least amount possible, this example here was made manually via "trial and error":

| Colour | Units | 80 | 70 | 70 | 80 | 80 | 10 | 10 | Left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pink | 240 | 80 |  | 70 |  | 80 |  | 10 |  |
| Peach | 240 |  | 70 | 70 |  | 80 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| Purple | 240 |  | 70 |  | 80 | 80 | 10 |  | 0 |
| Mint | 240 | 80 |  | 70 | 80 |  | 10 |  | 0 |
| Green | 240 | 80 | 70 |  | 80 |  |  | 10 | 0 |

Hopefully there's a way. Thanks in advance to anyone trying!

PS: i hope the tags are okay, i'm not sure really.

Comment: The good news is that you won't need more than ten packs, because that's exactly how many ways there are to choose three colours at a time from a set of five colours.

Comment: This does help, it's a piece of news i didn't know... however is there a "programmatical" way to calculate the amount of packs (in the second example table i ended up with 7 packs), or should i should always get 10 packs? also, is there a programmatical way to find the contents of each pack? (Note that the amount of colours may change, as well as the amount per colour i have to distribute), the only more or less fixed value would be the amount of colours per pack, which as far as i'm aware will always be 3).

Comment: You can model this with an integer linear programming problem. For example, try the following system using [HiGHS](https://lovasoa.github.io/highs-js/):
`Minimize
  obj: w_a + w_b + w_c + w_d + w_e
Subject To
  abc + abd + abe + acd + ace + ade + w_a = 242
  abc + abd + abe + bcd + bce + bde + w_b = 250
  abc + acd + ace + bcd + bce + cde + w_c = 240
  abd + acd + ade + bcd + bde + cde + w_d = 240
  abe + ace + ade + bce + bde + cde + w_e = 252
End`
Here the variable `abc` means "the number of packs consisting of colours $a,b,c$".

Comment: (cont'd) The variables $w_x$ are "waste" variables, which we seek to minimise. The first equation, $abc + abd + abe + acd + ace + ade + w_a = 242$, effectively counts all instances of colour $a$: it will show up in six different kinds of packs, and any leftover is counted in $w_a$. The algorithm gives the following (not necessarily unique) solution: $$(abc,abd,abe,acd,ace,ade,bcd,bce,bde,cde) = (0,0,84,156,2,0,0,82,84,0)$$
with no waste.

Comment: @Théophile thanks, seems quite useful, i'll try to learn to use it and experiment a little

Comment: @Théophile this is absolutely incredible, it works flawlessly even setting different bounds !!i love it, it's so awesome to have this, i'll have to investigate how it's done (though i doubt i'll be able to understand it and make code that does it, but its better than doing it by hand)!

Comment: Glad to help! The software itself is free, so you could consider writing code that simply generates the right system of equations and calls HiGHS to solve it. For more information, the field that covers this kind of problem (and many others) is called [Operations Research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_research), more specifically [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), and even more specifically [Integer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you have three of each color you can make five packs from them.  This tells you that your can use $240$ of each color to make $400$ packs.  This leaves you $24$ cards left.  You can make two packs of pink, peach, green which then leaves $8$ peach and $10$ green.  It should seem likely that you can mix things up a bit and use all the cards, getting $6$ more packs for a total of $408$.  I would trade two peach and four green into existing packs, pulling out blue each time.  You can then make six more packs with what is left.

Comment: This does help, it's a piece of news i didn't know... however is there a "programmatical" way to calculate the amount of packs (in the second example table i ended up with 7 packs), or should i should always get 10 packs? 
also, is there a programmatical way to find the contents of each pack? (Note that the amount of colours may change, as well as the amount per colour i have to distribute), the only more or less fixed value would be the amount of colours per pack, which as far as i'm aware will always be 3).

Comment: It depends.  If you have lots of cards and reasonable freedom in what goes into a pack you can pretty well count on using all the cards until you have too few to make a pack.  On the other hand, if the packs you are allowed to make are at all complex I believe the problem becomes NP-hard as it is a more difficult version of the knapsack problem.  Such problems are usually easy as you can quickly find a solution or find a reason there isn't one, but there are very difficult examples.

Answer (score 0):

let me suppose the amounts of candies are smaller, like 32, 40, 30, 30 and 42.

There are $10$ types of bags. The type that contains pink, peach and purple candies may be described as

$$ T_{khl} = 1 + k.h.l+ (k.h.l)^2 + (k.h.l)^3 + \cdots + (k.h.l)^{42} $$ meaning that it could be none of them or $1$ of such bag, or $2$, until a maximum of $42$.

The type that contains purple, mint and green is described as

$$  T_{lmg} = 1 + l.m.g + (l.m.g)^2 + (l.m.g)^3 + \cdots + (l.m.g)^{42} $$

To obtain all the possibilities of distribution, we have to multiply all ten enumerations
$$ T_{khl} \times T_{khm} \times \cdots \times T_{lmg} $$

and then read the coefficient of $$k^{32}h^{40}l^{30}m^{30}g^{42} = 110241$$.

These enumerating expressions are improperly named "generating functions".

They are not functions,

they list and not generate,

Plus sign is not a sum but a disjunction

and the multiplication sign is a conjunction.